# Converting String to Int causes FormatException

Tags: c#, string, int

I'm currently getting a value of a string and wanted to place it in an INT to start doing calculations.

string values e.g. is p2 = 33.7; Which is actually a temperature reading in Celsius

this is what i used to convert the p2 to INT:

```
value = Convert.ToInt32(p2);
tavg = val / cnter;
cnter++;
```

this code is what i use to place the value converted to a datagridview row cell:

```
 todayRow.Cells[index++].Value = tavg.ToString();
 this.weatherreport_dgv.Rows.Add(todayRow);
```

The error message given by the VS2013 is this:

"An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

The error is pointing to the conversion of p2 to INT

Comment: Why would you convert it to int and not a decimal, you are losing precision this way

Comment: ohh shoot! hahaha i just notice it know... ill try using double

Comment: double value = double.Parse(p1);
todayRow.Cells[index + 1].Value = value.ToString();

i tried this two but still the problems is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`33.7` is a decimal value, `Int32` only does integers. Use `Convert.ToDouble/double.Parse` to get a floating point value:

```
double value = double.Parse( p2 );
```

Or if you really do want it as an integer:

```
int value = (int)double.Parse( p2 );
```

You'll lose the decimals though.

Comment: Do this without the `(int)`-cast

Comment: well, of course I mean `double value = double.Parse( p2 );` :-)

Comment: Hehe yeah that made more sense!

Comment: i cant lose the decimal values so i tried to  use double.... but still it says the same thing...

Comment: Maybe the decimal-separator, the dot `.`, causes that problem. Depends on your culture.

Comment: good point about the culture problem ill try something then.. thanks for the idea

Comment: so i tried this code which i use in my other form to get rid of the culture problem: value = double.Parse(p1, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   but it seems the problem is still there... same error message on same line

Comment: Have you double-checked the actual value of `p2`. No extra characters in there?

Comment: i did.... i tried to directly place its value to the rows cells and the values are as expected.

Comment: You sure? Is `p2.Length` == 4?

Comment: Well `double.Parse( "33.7", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )` runs just fine on my computer at least..! Try that code in the Immediate Window once.

Comment: i think i got the answer. ill be posting it later. THANKS GUYS IM FALLING INLOVE WITH THIS WEBSITE <3

Answer (score 2):

use `int.TryParse` method !

```
int p = 0;

int.TryParse(p2, out p);
```

Also in your code the value is decimal that means you need to call:

```
decimal p = 0;

decimal.TryParse(p2, out p)
```

If the format of the string is not number it will return 0 for p. The problem comes from that you are giving wrong format.

**EDIT:**

You can set culture from which you will Parse the decimal. For an example if you are parsing decimal from french culture, because they have ',' in decimal you will need:

```
decimal.TryParse(qz, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"), out a);
```

Comment: so i tried this code which i use in my other form to get rid of the culture problem: value = double.Parse(p1, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); but it seems the problem is still there... same error message on same line

Comment: i did and i saw the problem after reapeting all the steps

Answer (score 0):

So here it is. I tried again all the step you all guys suggested and thats the only time when i notice that the first thrown value into my UDF is nothing. LOL XD stupid right? really sorry about that.

First thing i did is these:

```
if (p1.Length > 0) //To check the data fetch if its null or has a value at all.
```

And then i can be able to skip accepting null values in my UDF. Which is definitely good right?
Then i got this problem about CulturalInfo of the value because of its decimal placements.

So i used this code as suggested:

```
value = double.Parse(p2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//To convert value with decimal to Double
```

Since then i got a smoother flow of values running in my datagridview. 
Thanks a lot and more power to all of you guys!! xD

(Hope Stackoverflow wont delete this question to help others!)