# Reading data from serial port and comparing it in C#

Tags: c#

I have a simple program to read the data from a serial port and place it in the textbox. After that i want to take that data and perform other operations on it (comparing it...etc). The data received gets placed in the textbox, but when i convert it into an integer using Convert.Int32(textbox.Text), the program gives an error. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the portion of my code:

```
try
{
    textBox1.Text = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    switch (x)
    {
        case 1: textBox17.Text = "Received Number is 1"; break;
        case 2: textBox18.Text = "Received Number is 2"; break;
        case 3: textBox19.Text = "Received Number is 3"; break;
    }
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    label1.Text = "Timeout Exception";
}
```

I have got an exception of type `FormatException`, this is a screen shot for the exception message:
[image]

Comment: please write your exception

Comment: You only catch the `TimeoutException` but you don't catch Exception of other types like conversion exception. You should provide any error details and the string that you were trying to convert to Integer

Comment: @Mahmoud the error is at the Convert.ToInt32. The string i am receiving from PIC is a number. Can I know how the problem can be solved?

Comment: Add another catch block like the following `catch(Exception e){ // Put a break point here }` and put a break point as I demonstrated. After you get the exception please provide a screen shot or exception details. You didn't provide the error details.

Comment: @Mahmoud i have attached the error photo

Comment: Yes, as I expected it's a `FormatException` which means your string is in incorrect format, now you should provide the string that you were trying to convert.

Comment: @Mahmoud as i told you before. The String i am trying to convert (which is in textbox1.Text) is the number received from my PIC microcontroller, which is "1". And any thing received through serial port is a string and connot be considered as a number or integer. Thats why i converted it to an integer Thank you

Comment: No it's not, because that's why you get `FormatException`. put a break point  right on the `Convert.ToInt32`  and double check the string.  You may find some weird `ASCII` character, or new line character.

Comment: @Mahmoud but the thing is when i type: int x=textbox1.Text, or int x=SerialPort1.ReadExisting(), the program says it cant convert string to integer. That means the received data is a string, and thats why i am converting it to an integer, Is it possible you can please demonstate by correcting my code how the problem can be solved? Thanks alot

Comment: @F.Samm - Your string is not a number. That's why you're getting the `FormatException`. It is not `1`. It's something else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write

```
int x=textbox1.Text
```

Because you cannot [implicitly convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) between string and integer. You have an unhandled exception because you just have one `catch` block that catches only exceptions of type `TimeoutException`. The problem is that you have an exception of type `FormatException` and as there is no `catch` block that can catch this type of exception so the exception will go up your stack and unwind it until there is an appropriate catch block.

Now for the `FormatException`: there are many reasons why one get an exception of type `FormatException` but the general reason is that the `Convert` method failed to convert the string content to an integer value because it's in incorrect format! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692473/converting-string-to-int-causes-formatexception) you can find that if there was a decimal point in the string you will get this type of error. So your problem is in the string that you've read.